# How can I find a specific value in a file and store into a variable in a bash script?

Tags: php, bash, variables, search

I'm trying to achieve the following :

I have a config.php file which contains this line :

```
define('URL', 'www.website.com');
```

In my *bash* script I'd like to search inside *config.php*, find the value of *URL* and store it into a variable.

Any idea how that could be done ?

Comment: Would an acceptable solution be to make a PHP wrapper around config.php which outputs your constants in an easier-to-parse form? E.g. Name,Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
awk -F"[']" '/define/ && /URL/{print $4}' config.php
```

In order to assign to a variable, say:

```
var=$(awk -F"[']" '/define/ && /URL/{print $4}' config.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -P`:

```
grep -oP "^ *define *\( *'URL'[^']+'\K[^']+" config.php
www.website.com
```